# Multiple http requests in same flatMap method

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

After some research here I found out that the best way to make multiple requests in Rxjs is flatMap(). However, I can't get it to work when there's mulitple requests inside the flatMap() method aswell. The output in subscribe() is observables instead of values.

```
this.companyService.getSuggestions(reference)
    .pipe(
        flatMap((suggestions: string[]) => {
            let infos = [];
            suggestions.forEach(suggestion => {
                infos.push(this.companyService.getInformation(suggestion));
            }); 
            return of(infos);
        }),
    ).subscribe((val) => {
        console.log('subscribe', val); //Output here is array of observables instead of values
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flatMap will only wait for one value.

I would convert the suggestions string[] into a stream and do a flatMap over that.

```
import { flatMap, from } 'rxjs/operators'

const suggestionsRequest$ = this.companyService.getSuggestions(reference)

// convert to suggestion stream
const suggestions$ = suggestionsRequest$.pipe(
  flatMap((suggestions: string[]) => from(suggestions))
)

// get all infos
const infos$ = suggestions$.pipe(
  flatMap((suggestion: string) => this.companyService.getInformation(suggestion))
)
```